# Volumetric lights - origin point seen as a single point even with large radius

Tags: light, volumetrics

What can I do about point lights having very intense point of light at its origin when using volumetrics?

[image: V]

I realize this is the nature of a 'point' light, but what about when the 'radius' is turned up? I can't get the lighting to look realistic.

[image]

There's also a clearly defined 'origin' when using an area light, even when the area is substantially larger than what the volumetric origin is portraying.

If there's no simple solution to this, then how do you suggest lighting of this nature be done? A spot light leaves parts of the scene behind the light unlit, and *still* has a 'displayed volumetric origin' way smaller than any radius I set it to have.

Comment: I think the radius only affects the "center" brightness when using Cycles render engine.

Comment: So what could a work around be?

Comment: I guess that means you're using EEVEE? I'm not sure there is one due to the limitations of how it "fast calculates" lighting. That doesn't mean it's necessarily impossible, it might just take a much more complex setup to achieve - one that I'm not currently aware of. I'll see If I can find anything.

Comment: A simple solution could just be to use multiple lights, like six, in place of each one. Not optimal, not optimised, but it'd work.